# how to show "(base)" in directory path using anconda with powerlevel10k

Tags: python, anaconda, oh-my-zsh

I'm using powerlevel10k theme, oh-my-zsh on iterm2.

got a school project using anaconda, so i downloaded it.

it goes well, but there's a problem.

i wanna see "(base)" before the "~" on my directory path while i'm in anaconda virtual environment, but because of using powerlevel10k theme (maybe), it only shows "~" whether i'm in virtual or not.

[image]

i googled, and found that "~/.p10k.zsh" file controls the setting.
[image]

i comment out "truncate_to_unique" to make "typeset -g POWEWRLEVEL9K_SHORETEN_STRATEGY="

but it does not work.

what should i do now??

it would be great to see "(base)"+current directory while using anaconda, and to see only current directory while not.

Answer (score 0):

oh i find the answer.
the keyword is POWERLEVEL9K_VIRTUALENV_SHOW_WITH_PYENV
make "false" to "true".
then it shows your enviornment on the right side.